# I change margin on <main> tag and it makes <body> not take up the whole screen

Tags: html, css

a have a very simple static page,which looks like this:
[image]

But if I change the padding of  to 0, suddenly  stops to cover the whole screen:
[image]

I used Chrome for this. Tell me, why this kind of strange behavior can happen?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/app.css">

</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <article>
            <h1>
                <a href="/posts/the-work-post">
                    The Work Post
                </a>
            </h1>
            <p>
                <a href="/categories/work"> Work </a>
            </p>

            A little work never killed nobody, you soft pretzel!

        </article>
        
        <article>
            <h1>
                <a href="/posts/the-family-post">
                    The Family Post
                </a>
            </h1>
            <p>
                <a href="/categories/family"> Family </a>
            </p>
            Find a family, watcha waiting for?
        </article>
    </main>
</body>
```

CSS (with ommited coloring):

```
html {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }
 
 body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

main{
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    min-height: 1080px;
    padding: 1px;

}

article{
    margin: 15px 10px;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(247, 239, 246);
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/, https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse/